# deploying Field level security

Tags: deployment, fls

what is different from force.com 28 to 31?

i was able to move the field level security using force.com 28 without adding profiles to the package. but with the newer versions of Force.com >= 31  it is impossible to move the FLS without adding profiles to the deploy package.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying? Ant, change sets, etc

Comment: I tried Ant & eclipse

Comment: You need to include profiles, if you are deploying change sets. Not sure about Ant though.